# Connecting to a remote Ubuntu 18.04 Server with only Servername, Username and Password provided to set up a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, ssh-tunnel, pgadmin-4

Im currently in a Group Project for University in which we are supposed to create a web application with a database in the background, running on a Server from the University. Our prof gave us Servername, Username and passwort to an Ubuntu 18.04 Server and told us to connect via SSH and then install the software needed for the database.

Unfortunately if i use pgAdmin trying to connect to the Server, i get the Error message

"Unable to connect to server:
server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request."

I entered Servername, Username and Password in the General tab as well as in the SSH Tunneling tab, leaving the rest blank or on default.

It would be nice if anyone could give some Tips on how to connect to the Server (is there an better way than pgAdmin) or if i am missing steps?

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you able to connect to the pg server from the cloud itself (locally)

Answer (score 0):

> Our prof gave us Servername, Username and passwort to an Ubuntu 18.04 Server and told us to connect via SSH and then install the software needed for the database.

Right, so then do that.  You can't use pgadmin4 to install database software on the remote side of an ssh tunnel.  pgadmin4 is for administering a database which already exists, not for installing the database software itself.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install PostgreSQL Database on the server. For that, you connect via SSH to the server and install the database software. After the first step is done and the PostgreSQL is up and running, you can connect with pgAdmin. As said before, pgAdmin is for managing PostgreSQL Databases, not for installing the database software itself.